# Configuring Emacs and especially undo-tree-mode for tiling window managers

Tags: frames, undo-tree-mode

I want to use Emacs in a frame-oriented fashion and let my tiling window manager handle buffer organization. For example, following this [tutorial](http://compsoc.man.ac.uk/~shep/tearing-out-the-emacs-window-manager.html). By default, Emacs packages such as undo-tree-mode seem to be dependent on windows to display the visualization. Am I wrong on this? Can I make undo-tree-mode default to opening the visualizer in another frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first basic step would be to

```
(setq pop-up-frames t)
```

so that `display-buffer` always makes a new frame.

A lot of further (but more complicated) customizations are described in the ["One On One" Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OneOnOneEmacs) project by Drew Adams.

Comment: I've actually set this to t and set pop-up-windows to nil, but wasn't able to get it working with undo-tree-visualize.

Comment: @wdkrnls Doing that works fine for me. Are you using the latest version of undo tree?

Comment: My apologies. It seems like my issue was intermittent. It seems to be working fine with pup-up-frames now.